PDAL Translates Removes LAS Attributes
I am using PDAL (pdal 2.7.1 (git-version: Release)) "Translate" for assigning a CRS to my ALS pointcloud (format LAS; point format 6).
However, everything works fine, but some Attributes (Amplitude, Reflectance and Deviation) are missing after translation. Also  I checked that point format changed after translating from Point Format 6 to Point Format 3 (can be seen in CC).
Anyone knows what's going on here? Is there another way of translating pointclouds? Is it possible to use some commands to keep the original format?
By the way, here's a code snippet I am using to get this error (nothing special):
pdal translate -i "INPUT" -o "OUTPUT" --writers.las.a_srs="EPSG:XXXXX"


I found the answer. PDAL uses as standard format LAS1.2. The pointcloud I use is LAS1.4. So the translate process downgraded the Version to 1.2, so additional attribute fields are lost.
I had to add the field  `"minor_version" : "4" and also changed the code to JSON Format. Please find below a correct working example:
[
    {
        "type" : "readers.las",
        "filename" : "INPUT"
    },
    {
        "type" : "writers.las",
        "extra_dims": "all",
        "minor_version" : "4",
        "a_srs": "EPSG:XXXXX",
        "filename" : "OUTPUT"
    }
]


Indeed the default output format is 1.2. You can also use --writers.las.forward to bring all of the header settings over.
